# How to debug the score value calculated for a document and query string which is displayed on solr admin console?

Tags: solr, relevance

I have indexed few documents and now while trying to query a string from solr admin console, I am able to retrieve score value for each result retrieved by selecting field as score. But I would need to check the doc score, termfreq and other parameters considered for calculating this score which can help me to debug and understand. Can anyone help me with the possible ways? Are there any certain keywords or fields or query parameters to be specified while querying from solr admin console? Solr Version that I am using is 7.6.0.

Comment: In addition to MatsLindh answer below, this blog post explains the basics of the `explain` information that the debug option returns: https://library.brown.edu/DigitalTechnologies/understanding-scoring-of-documents-in-solr/

Comment: I'll also recommend [explain.solr.pl](https://explain.solr.pl/) which visualizes the debug information for you.

Comment: Thank you Mats and Hector! Provided information and links is helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Add `debug=all`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/common-query-parameters.html#CommonQueryParameters-ThedebugParameter) (the new version of `debugQuery=true`) to your query string. It'll include a detailed explanation of how each part of your query contributes to the score.